# How do I change my workspace in Team Foundation Server 2005 and 2008?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2005

I have multiple projects in a couple of different workspaces. However, it seems like I can never figure out how to change my current workspace. The result is that files that I have checked out on my machine are shown to be checked out by somebody else and are not accessible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean "workspace", not "workstation", as your question doesn't quite make sense to me otherwise.

In Visual Studio, go to the Source Control Explorer (View->Other Windows->Source Control Explorer).  At the top of the source control explorer window you should have a toolbar with a few buttons.  Somewhere on that toolbar (for me it's at the right) there should be a Workspace dropdown.  Just select the workspace you want to use from that dropdown.

Answer (score 11):

Are you wanting to change the location of the files on the workstation?  If so, here's how I do it:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Open the Source Control Explorer window.
3. From the Workspace dropdown select "Workspaces..."
4. The Manage Workspaces dialog should show up.
5. Select the workspace you want to modify, and click Edit...
6. You should be able to adjust the folders from here.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should active you workspace window.

1. choose the window menu
2. click Source Control Explore.
3. click Active button.
4. The Workspace window appears
5. click the WorkSpace name in Workspace window.
6. from the popup list choose the Workspace name you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2013
If you just regret which local folder you choose for a project under version control. Do like follows: 
In the Source Control Explorer in the Folders pane
Select the project which local folder destination/mapping you are not pleased with.
Right click. --> Advanced --> Remove mapping. 
A window opens: Press the browse button and choose another local folder for the project and then click "Change".

Answer (score 0):

Click on: `File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspace` and then you can edit or remove the existing mapped locations

Answer (score -1):

I don't entirely understand your question.

Are you saying that files you check out on one machine seems to be unaccessible on another of your machines? I'd say that would be entirely by design, as now you have a file that has local modifications done on one machine, which may or may not be available on your other machines.

When you say *checked out by somebody else*, what does that mean exactly? How are you verifying this, what are you looking at?

Or do you mean something else? In that case, please elaborate.